# startActivityForResult не вызывает запуск onActivityResult при использовании Parcelable объектов в Intent

Tags: android, activity, android-parcelable

С простыми типами данных все работало, но когда пришлось переписать под передачу Parcelable объектов через Intent, onActivityResult перестал вызываться

вызов второго Activity в первом

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick position: " + position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ID_KEY, position);
            intent.putExtra(PRODUCTNAME,mProducts.get(position));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EDIT_TYPE);
        }
```

Открывается второй Activity, где Parcelable объект успешно обрабатывается и при нажатии ОК второе Activity завершает работу

```
public void onOKClick (View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OK click");
    String mProductName = productName.getText().toString();
    double mProductEnergy = Double.parseDouble(productEnergy.getText().toString());
    double mProductProtein = Double.parseDouble(productProtein.getText().toString());
    double mProductFat = Double.parseDouble(productFat.getText().toString());
    double mProductCarbohydrate = Double.parseDouble(productCarbohydrate.getText().toString());
    Product mProduct = new Product(mProductName,mProductEnergy,mProductProtein,mProductFat,mProductCarbohydrate);
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(ProductsFragment.ID_KEY,position);
    data.putExtra(ProductsFragment.PRODUCTNAME,mProduct);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
    finish();
}
```

При нажатии Cancel тоже

```
public void onCancelClick (View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "Cancel click");
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}
```

Ну и собственно onActivityResult первого

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"OnActivityResult");
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_EDIT_TYPE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Request edit");
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Log.d(TAG, "Result OK");
            int position = data.getIntExtra(ID_KEY,0);
            Product mProduct = (Product) data.getParcelableExtra(PRODUCTNAME);
            mProducts.add(mProduct);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Edit canceled");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Result super");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Notify data changed");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Что при нажатии OK, что при нажатии Cancel onActivityResult не выполняется, что видно как по сообщениям в дебаге, так и по поведению приложения.

Пробовал назначать свои переменные RESULT_OK и RESULT_CANCELED, так как в Activity и во Fragment они разные.
Находил информацию, что нужно только положительные их значения - не правда.
Что самое странное Parcelable объект Product прекрасно передается с помощью Intent так как второе Activity его правильно распаковывает и обрабатывает, а onActivityResult даже с пустым Intent не хочет выполняться

Comment: А `REQUEST_EDIT_TYPE` у вас положительный?

Comment: Ещё может быть такое: содержимое Bundle в Intent больше 1Mb и до, вроде, 7 версии ОС это тихо крашит, что выглядит, как "ничего не происходит".

Comment: Ну или у вас в манифесте что-то не то в `launchMode` для активити прописано.

Comment: Я надеюсь `@Override` вы умышленно не стали писать в вопросе, и на самом деле он есть перед `onActivityResult`

Comment: REQUEST_EDIT_TYPE положительный.
С размером Bundle точно быть уверенным не могу, но во второе Activity тот же самый объект передает. И при Cancel он не передается вовсе, а при этом onActivityResult все равно не выполняется. @Override в коде, естественно есть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Попробовал все варианты 'launchMode'. Изначально было 'standard'

Comment: Может вы Parcelable не так реализовали. Покажите его код

Comment: @ЮрийСПб похоже проблема всё таки не в Parceble. Сейчас вернул обратно реализацию с примитивными типами данных, а onActivityResult не выполняется

Comment: [Вызывающее Activity](https://github.com/seysen/HikingMealsForAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/seysen/hikingmealsforandroid/fragments/ProductsFragment.java) [Вызываемое Activity](https://github.com/seysen/HikingMealsForAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/seysen/hikingmealsforandroid/ProductDetailActivity.java)

Comment: @seysen, у вас некоторая путаница. Вызывающий класс - не активити, но фрагмент. Сам код, вроде, правильный. В нём проблемы не видно. Возможно проблема в активити, которая содержит фрагмент. Покажите её код.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб [Основной Activity](https://github.com/seysen/HikingMealsForAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/seysen/hikingmealsforandroid/MainActivity.java) который содержит фрагменты

Comment: @seysen, см. ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы явно указали не вызывать `onActivityResult` во фрагментах, которые содержатся в `MainActivity`, не вызвав `super.onActivityResult()` в `MainActivity`.

Вызовите `super.onActivityResult()` в `MainActivity` или просто удалите этот метод, раз в нём нет кода.